# Can i add MVC project in normal asp.net c# project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

can anybody tell me that if i made a normal asp.net c# project and in that solution i want to add mvc project. so is it possible to call mvc view from normal page which is in first project? if yes then how can i call view page from normal page of asp.net c# project.
on live server how can i call mvc page?
Thanks
Samir

Answer (score 0):

[Mixing VB ASP.NET and C# ASP.MVC projects in a single solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419961/mixing-vb-asp-net-and-c-asp-mvc-projects-in-a-single-solution)

Comment: this is not the proper solution. can you give me an example.

Comment: what example do you want? Link above is just simple pager - and you can use it to build your own grid.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, couple of different things here.

Can a ASP.NET forms project exist in the same solution?  Yes

Can you mix MVC with WebForms in the same project? No

Can a MVC site communicate with a WebForms site?  Yes, you can easily pass between via simulated form submission or by URL.  You could also configure cookies to work across both sites.

Can you have an MVC site and a WebForms site use the same url? No

Comment: By winforms I guess you mean webforms? If that is the case then you can mix them in the same project.

Comment: Then you can use them in the same project without problems.

Comment: can anybody give me an example so i can better understand.

Comment: @Samir, What is it that you want to know?

Comment: @Samir, Here is a article that describes how you can use asp.net mvc and asp.net webforms in the same project: http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/11/running-asp-net-webforms-and-asp-net-mvc-side-by-side.aspx